# Android studio: Android device freezes after crash

Tags: android, android-studio

New at Android. I am testing my app via Android Studio, running, not debugging. My device is a Samsung S2, API level 16.

Almost every exception freezes the device and requires restart or even battery remove&insert. Any solution to this?

UPDATE:
This seems not to be code related and happens on different projects. Any NullPointerException for instance would cause the device's screen to turn black. Sometimes the device will restart itself, other times I would have to remove the battery and re-insert it.

Comment: Do you use custom exception handler?

Comment: With which code You have tested this? For example, if You have made by mistake an infinite loop, then it could happen that some devices hang for a long time.

Comment: Could you add some code which reproduces this ?

Comment: @JonasCz, but probably you'll need his device as well :)

Comment: @DominikSuszczewicz nope, what's that? ;-)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Anything really. Last thing that got the device freeze is trying to reach a array which was out of bounds: titles[6] (only had 5). I got an index out of bound exception and the device froze. Had to remove and re-insert the battery. I know see this is not a typical behaviour so I am wondering if anyone had encountered this in his android programming experience? Perhaps it is because the device is quite dated or perhaps because I am using a custom launcher...

Comment: Do You mean only a launcher or a complete custom rom? This depends on the rom, maybe that´s the cause...

Comment: No, this isn't typical behaviour, and the problem is not that the device is dated (it should work, my gs1 works great for development). I'd guess that either something is messed up with the firmware (custom ROM ?) or data on the device, or there is something wrong with the hardware, eg. worn-out and corrupted flash memory (It's a few years old, and if it's never gotten a factory reset, it's quite possible that something has become inconsistent and broken).